# Maybe Task not supported on outbound ports?

Tags: elm, option-type

I seem to be getting this error

```
Trying to send an unsupported type through outbound port `projectRequests`

    port projectRequests : Signal (Maybe (Task String ()))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The specific unsupported type is:

   Task.Task String ()

The types of values that can flow through outbound ports include: Ints, Floats, Bools, Strings, Maybes, Lists, Arrays, Tuples, Json.Values, and concrete records.
```

However this seems to be fine

```
port orgRequests : Signal (Task String ())
```

I am confused as to what is going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can use a [port](http://elm-lang.org/guide/interop#ports):

1. Send data to out to JavaScript, where you write your own handler to deal with it. This is limited to a [subset of data](http://elm-lang.org/guide/interop#customs-and-border-protection) that can be easily transformed to JS values.
2. Send `Task`s to the runtime to be scheduled for execution.

In this case you have data (`Maybe`) wrapped around your `Task`, so the compiler assumes (wrongly*) that you want to the use the port for purpose #1.

If you want to execute the `Task`s wrapped in `Just`s on the `Signal` and do nothing on a `Nothing` on the `Signal`, you can filter out the `Nothing` and unwrap the `Just` with [`Signal.Extra.filter`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.3.0/Signal-Extra#filter) or `Signal.filterMap identity`:

```
port projectRequests : Signal (Maybe (Task String ()))
port projectRequests = Signal.filterMap identity -- and then whatever you had here before
```

*Can you please report this error message to the [error message catalog](https://github.com/evancz/error-message-catalog)? This message could be better since it can guess your intentions from the `Task` being in the type of the data you're trying to send out.